# How do I kill a pig which was turned into a zombie pigman by lightning in SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

## no longer applicable for minecraft versions beta 1.6 and later

While playing on a Minecraft SMP bukkit server, I tried using the `/thor` command to manipulate lightning on a few pigs with my pickaxe.

[image: lightning on pigs]

But it seems that I can't kill it, I even tried putting them in a pit and hitting them with a diamond sword, to no avail. However, they still make the damage sound.

[image: zombie pigmen in a pit]

I even tried using the `/butcher` command provided with WorldEdit, but it still would not work!

[image: /butcher does not work]

So, how do I kill the zombie pigmen?

**EDIT:**

I know that restarting the server, unloading the chunk on the server etc. will despawn the mob, but what I want to do is to ***kill*** it. So,

1. Is this a bug?
2. Does it happen in other servers?
3. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You could always just bury them, and forget about them.

Comment: Burying them alive is cruel, I prefer killing them swiftly :P

Comment: Might this be a client-server bug? Perhaps the zombie pigmen exist only in your client—since damage is server-side, you wouldn't be able to kill them. Disconnecting and reconnecting would fix it, if that's the case.

Comment: Had to ask: Texture Pack?

Comment: the texture pack is [SimpleCraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=104854).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a glitch with Minecraft that it also spawns multiple pigmen from one pig. The easiest way is to disconnect and reconnect. They should disappear.

This has happened in my server.

And it IS a client side bug like SevenSidedDie said.

Comment: +1 -- 13 hours with no second answer and then we answer the same within 52 seconds...

Comment: Confirmed as a bug, now fixed in 1.6: [`* Fixed pigs getting hit by lightning in multiplayer spawning client-side zombie pigmen` (link)](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/5775170768/the-changelist-for-1-6)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Why don't you post ***that*** as an answer then?

Comment: @Ull I think SmilingDevil covers the "it's a bug" answer just fine, and I'm happy to just contribute to it. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: pssh, you're too nice. :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with invulnerable pigs appearing client-side only from a *chicken* spawner. Dis- and reconnecting makes them vanish. This is a bug, you cannot kill them.

Answer (score 4):

Try getting everyone on the server to leave the area, and come back.  The easiest way I can think of to achieve this if there are a lot of people playing is to try a server reset.  This should cause them to despawn.

**Edit**
As I've found out on my own server, this is purely client-side.  Logging out and back in should make them disappear.

Comment: I had a similar experience, but it's not necessary for anyone else to disconnect since this bug is client-side

Comment: -0 - since bckbck accepted [SmilingDevil's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22245/how-do-i-kill-a-pig-which-was-turned-into-a-zombie-pigman-by-lightning-in-smp/22282#22282), yours is incorrect (in this case) and its execution would be unnecessarily  inconvenient for players. Then again, this could help for other issues so I won't downvote either